# Some video and audio properties missing while recording with getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia, transcoding, webcam-capture

I am using the below code to record a video through web cam and I need to transcribe this and take the audio from that video and find some keyword match percent. 
The video is recording and sending to server, displaying properly also. But there are some audio and video properties missing when I checked in the video details, expecting, this is the issue that i am not able to use the proper audi from this video for my keyword match percent. 
This is my code.
Please help me. 
Thanks in advance

```
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>MediaCapture and Streams API</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>
          <h1>MediaCapture, MediaRecorder and Streams API</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit molestiae itaque facere totam saepe tempore esse temporibus, quae reprehenderit aliquid iusto ea laborum, iure eligendi odio exercitationem sapiente illum quos.</p>

          <p><button id="btnStart">START RECORDING</button><br/>
          <button id="btnStop">STOP RECORDING</button></p>

          <video controls></video>

          <video id="vid2" controls></video>

          <!-- could save to canvas and do image manipulation and saving too -->
      </main>
      <script>

          let constraintObj = {
              audio: false,
              video: {
                  facingMode: "user",
                  width: { min: 640, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
                  height: { min: 480, ideal: 720, max: 1080 }
              }
          };
          // width: 1280, height: 720  -- preference only
          // facingMode: {exact: "user"}
          // facingMode: "environment"

          //handle older browsers that might implement getUserMedia in some way
          if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
              navigator.mediaDevices = {};
              navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraintObj) {
                  let getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
                  if (!getUserMedia) {
                      return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
                  }
                  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                      getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraintObj, resolve, reject);
                  });
              }
          }else{
              navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
              .then(devices => {
                  devices.forEach(device=>{
                      console.log(device.kind.toUpperCase(), device.label);
                      //, device.deviceId
                  })
              })
              .catch(err=>{
                  console.log(err.name, err.message);
              })
          }

          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraintObj)
          .then(function(mediaStreamObj) {
              //connect the media stream to the first video element
              let video = document.querySelector('video');
              if ("srcObject" in video) {
                  video.srcObject = mediaStreamObj;
              } else {
                  //old version
                  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStreamObj);
              }

              video.onloadedmetadata = function(ev) {
                  //show in the video element what is being captured by the webcam
                  video.play();
              };

              //add listeners for saving video/audio
              let start = document.getElementById('btnStart');
              let stop = document.getElementById('btnStop');
              let vidSave = document.getElementById('vid2');
              let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
              let chunks = [];

              start.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
                  mediaRecorder.start();
                  console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
              })
              stop.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
                  mediaRecorder.stop();
                  console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
              });
              mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
                  chunks.push(ev.data);
              }
              mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{
                  let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4;' });
                  chunks = [];
                  let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  vidSave.src = videoURL;
              }
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err.name, err.message);
          });

          /*********************************
          getUserMedia returns a Promise
          resolve - returns a MediaStream Object
          reject returns one of the following errors
          AbortError - generic unknown cause
          NotAllowedError (SecurityError) - user rejected permissions
          NotFoundError - missing media track
          NotReadableError - user permissions given but hardware/OS error
          OverconstrainedError - constraint video settings preventing
          TypeError - audio: false, video: false
          *********************************/
      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to record the audio, you should change the parameter from `audio: false` to `audio:true`.

```
let constraintObj = {
              audio: false,
              video: {
                  facingMode: "user",
                  width: { min: 640, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
                  height: { min: 480, ideal: 720, max: 1080 }
              }
```

Comment: Hi sir, Thanks for the information. i tried that too. audio is coming. its showing in the player too. But still some properties are missing. transcribe is not working

Comment: Where is your code for transcribing?  You'd probably need to use a service like those in Google Cloud, Azure or AWS to do a live transcription of the audio.

Comment: Hi sir, actually I am saving thing video to the server. Then the video is taken from there and transcribed later. its not done together. In that case, other uploaded videos are transcribing. only this recorded video is not getting keyword matches